# Express: Pass the response of a method to another method in the same post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have two subparts in my `app.post`, the first one return a string called **customToken** which I want to pass as a parameter into the second one.

Could somebody remind me where I am getting it wrong?

I get an error of **Can't set headers after they are sent.**

```
app.post('/.custom-token', function (req, res, nex) {
    var token = null;

    //part ONE
    admin.auth().createCustomToken(req.body.uid)
        .then(function(customToken) {
            console.log("Successfully created custom-token:", customToken);
            res.status(200).send({token: customToken});
            nex();
            return token = res.status(200).send({token: customToken});
        })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
        res.status(400).send({error: error})

    });

    //part TWO: i need to pass in the token generated above
    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
        .then(function (firebaseUser) {
            //...
        })
        .catch(function(error) {                       
            // ...
        });
});
```

Comment: One issue is that you are calling res.status(200).send twice which will call res.end() twice that might be causing the problem

Comment: @AsifSaeed how can i pass the `customToken` into the second part as a parameter?

Comment: let write it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by promise chaining

```
 app.post('/.custom-token', function (req, res, nex) {
    var token = null;

    //part ONE
    admin.auth().createCustomToken(req.body.uid)
        .then(function(customToken) {
            console.log("Successfully created custom-token:", customToken);
            return customToken;
        })
        .then(function(token){
             // token returned in the last promise will be available here in token parameter
            return firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
        })
        .then(function(firebaseUser){
                //....
                //here you can send response back
                return res.status(200).send();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
            res.status(400).send({error: error})

        });
});
```

The second part in your code will run without waiting for the response from first part because of async so token will be null for second part of your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **middleware**, something as follow.:

```
const getUserToken = (req, res, next) => {
    admin.auth().createCustomToken(req.body.uid)
        .then(function(customToken) {
            console.log("Successfully created custom-token:", customToken);
            req.cutomToken = customToken;

        //Here will pass the control to the next handler
            next();

        })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
        res.status(400).send({error: error});
        res.end();
    });
});
```

You use the **middleware** here.

```
app.post('/.custom-token',getUserToken ,function (req, res, next) {
     const token = req.cutomToken;
     firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)
        .then(function (firebaseUser) {
            //...
        })
        .catch(function(error) {                       
            // ...
        });
});
```

This has the advantage that you can reuse the middleware on several endpoints.
Hope this help.